# me pueden decir a saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?, trato de sumar los numeros entre el 1 y el 3

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola, que tal estoy atorado con un problema, llevo dos horas, ya intente de todo, ya eh buscado y no encuentro mi error..

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: ¿No será que olvidaste usar el arreglo que se pasa como parámetro?

Comment: pero el array que se pasa como parametro es 'numeros' no? de ahi estoy sacando el inicio y el final, para que la variable 'i' tenga una reverencia y pueda sumar a la variable 'suma' o al menos eso era que lo que yo creia pero obviamente estoy mal, si no pasara el test.

Comment: Nunca estás usando el arreglo le pasas a la función. Siempre vas a sumar los números del 1 al 3 porque tienes declarado `var numeros = [1,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que *estás usando un array que tu mismo has declarado no el que te están pasando como parámetro*
Entonces, en lugar de declarar `var números = [1,3]` y usarla como parámetros, debes hacer uso de la variable array por lo tanto inicio y fin deberían quedar así:

```
var inicio = array[0]
var fin = array[1]
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, en efecto ese era mi error, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Otra cosa, te recomiendo usar `let` en lugar de `var`, el uso de var ya no está recomendado. https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/var-let-y-const-cual-es-la-diferencia/

Comment: gracias lo hare.